# Mongodb: Is it possible to group by creation date using object id?

Tags: mongodb

One of our schemas relies on the object id as a record of creation date.  However, I'd like to query the collection returning results grouped by the date of creation.

Is this possible with objectId?

Comment: Only with MR currently, there is a JIRA somewhere for the aggregation framework to be able to use objectId as a timestamp

Comment: @Sammaye - ok thanks.  Probably we'll have to extract the dates out into a real field then.  What's MR?